# State does not get updated with React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures, react-hooks

I thought I got my head around closures in hooks. However, I'm struggling with this one. The code below is a very simplified version of my actual code for demonstration. In reality, `clickHandler()` and `upload()` are far more complex. That's why it's not an option to combine them into one function. The issue is that I can't access the updated files array from the state in the upload function. If I use a ref for the array it works, however, I think it's an antipattern. I also tried to declare the state outside the component, which didn't work. Thanks for your help.

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';

const HomeScreen = () => {

    const initialState = {
        error: false,
        files: [],
        totalSize: 0,
        finished: false
    };

    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

    const upload = useCallback(() => {
        // At this point state.files is an empty array
        console.log(state.files);
    }, [state]);

    const clickHandler = useCallback(() => {
        const queue = [
            { id: 1, bool: false },
            { id: 2, bool: false }
        ];

        setState((state) => {
            return { ...state, files: queue }
        });

        upload()

    }, [upload]);

    return <button onClick={clickHandler}>Click me</button>;
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

state updates using hooks state updater is asynchronous and hence when you call upload from within `clickHandler` the updated state isn't available to you. The simplest solution to pass the state to the upload method

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';

const HomeScreen = () => {

    const initialState = {
        error: false,
        files: [],
        totalSize: 0,
        finished: false
    };

    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

    const upload = useCallback((updatedState) => {
        // At this point state.files is an empty array
        console.log((updatedState || state).files);
    }, [state]);

    const clickHandler = useCallback(() => {
        const queue = [
            { id: 1, bool: false },
            { id: 2, bool: false }
        ];

        setState((state) => {
            const updatedState = { ...state, files: queue }
            upload(updatedState )
            return updatedState;
        });

        upload()

    }, [upload]);

    return <button onClick={clickHandler}>Click me</button>;
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I thought about this as well and tried to add some timeouts, which didn't work either. Could you explain why? Is it because of a new closure within the setTimeout function?

Answer (score 0):

For your `upload()` function to have access to the current state it must be called from a `useEffect()`. See if that works for you?

```js
const HomeScreen = () => {

    const initialState = {
        error: false,
        files: [],
        totalSize: 0,
        finished: false
    };
    
    const [state, setState] = React.useState(initialState);

    const upload = React.useCallback(() => {
        // At this point state.files is an empty array
        console.log(state.files);
    }, [state]);
    
    React.useEffect(()=>{
      state.files.length ? upload() :  null;
    },[state]);

    const clickHandler = React.useCallback(() => {
        const queue = [
            { id: 1, bool: false },
            { id: 2, bool: false }
        ];

        setState((state) => {
            return { ...state, files: queue }
        });

        //upload()

    }, [upload]);

    return <button onClick={clickHandler}>Click me</button>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<HomeScreen/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```